# JQUERY CSS "display" "block" does not work even though "display" "none" does work....

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, block, display

Hello guys I'm working on an online comic right now and am struggeling with following jquery code. 
Jquery is supposed to change my css code from the #compscreen2 image from "display:none" to "display:block" after the other function happens but it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.... any help please?
It seems to work for the other image though.... #compscreen display:none does work. Help!

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//function for automated top scrolling
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
  scrollPosY();

  if ($('#panel11').visible(true) && scrolled == 0) {
  $('html, body').stop().animate( { scrollTop: $('.scrollpanel').offset().top }, 500 )
  scrolled = 1;
  $("div.wrap2").remove();
  $("#compscreen2").css("display","block");
  $("#compscreen").css("display", "none"); 
  }
});

$window = $(window);


});
```

CSS :

```
#compscreen2 img{
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can u post a web inspector screenshot or create a JSBin? Since ```position: absolute``` did you check the top position of the element? Maybe its simply off the page...

Comment: css selector `#compscreen2 img` but jQuery selector `#compscreen2`...

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML that this code is manipulating? Maybe you could make a pen at [Codepen](http://codepen.io) with the HTML, JS and CSS and then we can inspect it. I can't see anything that essentially could cause the code not to work.

Comment: Have  you set the by default property of compscreen2 as display:none?  or you loading later by using ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css sets `display: none` for `#compscreen2 img`, not `#compscreen2` itself. You can either make the css something like this:

```
#compscreen2 {
    display: none;
}

#compscreen2 img {
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

or change the js to:

```
$("#compscreen2 img").css("display","block");
```

You can also use helper functions [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to make the code a bit more readable.

Comment: thank you so much!!  it worked. Also thanks for the advice :) yayy!!